# No module named bs4.element

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a script that imports bs4 as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I do not have bs4 installed, rather, I included the `bs4` directory from `beautifulsoup4-4.4.1` (from http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) in the same directory as my script.

When I run this script directly from the command prompt (on a Windows 7 VirtualBox VM)

```
python myscript.py
```

the import works just fine (and so does the rest of my script).

But I need to run this script from a larger framework, where it is called as part of a module from some other Python code. I cannot be more specific on this, because the framework is owned by my company.

My script is called correctly untill it gets to the point where it imports bs4. I get the following error:

```
No module named bs4.element
```

This code runs on the same Windows 7 VirtualBox VM as above. I made sure the bs4 diretcory is on `PYTHONPATH` (with path as `C:\Users\me\path-to-bs4`). I know bs4 is found, because when I add a print statement to the very top of `bs4/__init__.py` I see the result on my output.

I am at a loss as to what causes this problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I am using Python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible `bs4/element.py` is masked by another Python script called `element.py` somewhere on the path.

Would someone kindly improve this answer with a better explanation, or verify it's correct?

This possibility has been mentioned in other SO questions as well, I did not realise it could also be applied to my situation, because our framework has no other script called `element.py`. But the conflicting script could also be part of external modules we import.

It's also still possible this is not the reason I get the `no module named bs4.element` error.

My workaround is that I used `pip` to install bs4 on the VM.